# Is SNPRelate the goto package for PCA of SNP data in R?

Tags: r, snp, plink, phylogenetics, pca

I'm trying to evaluate a method that I'm not familiar with. They used SNPRelate. I'm wondering if this is the best / only choice... what other tools would you recommend?

Many thanks,

Comment: Does it have to be in R? If not, the standard things to make a PCA from genotype matrix is plink or eigenstrat.

Comment: That said, unless you are doing fancy stuff like PCA projection - PCA is just PCA and whilst methods might differ in terms of computational compexity, the resulting eigenvectors will be mostly very similar.

Comment: SNPRelate claims nearly 10x faster than plink... but I don't know.